# Button Image Slideshow For Metro App

Tags: button, windows-8, microsoft-metro, slideshow, photos

I am trying to create a button that has multiple images that scroll through like in the windows 8 photos app.(EDIT) Meaning the individual button. Like how each button scrolls through the images inside the album it links to.(EDIT) But I have had zero luck. Any help would be appreciated because i have not clue where to start.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to accomplish this. Do you prefer handling things in Code Behind? If so, I would use databinding against a view object that had a timer that shifted the "CurrentDisplayImagePath" once in a while, giving you full control over the process.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are refering to a flipview

Here is official documentation on how to make a flipview for javascript and html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465425.aspx

Heres the one for VB
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh781233(v=win.10).aspx

if you have more questions please comment

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it without writing codes. I'm not familar with codes. But I've made one like what you said: the button is a slideshow and each picture links to different pages. If you do not mind spend some time, you can try Photo Flash Maker. This is the program I use. I'm sure it can help you. You may even email me if you have any quesitons about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Starting with this, and make changes whatever you like..

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image   />
        <Image   />
        <Image   />
        <Image   />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Refer Scrollviewer, StackPanel and Image tags on MSDN site for detailed properties and events related to them.

Comment: Sorry shouldve specified more, i meant the actual buttons themselves, not a scroller

Comment: Can you elaborate the "Button" that you want, what it should do or how does it look ?

Comment: They are Buttons that lead to the different albums and they change their face to different images inside the albums every so many seconds